# Strategy to put trusted certs into the trust store?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, openssl, security, keytool

I hav a client certifcate chain like

individual cert -> Intermediate cert -> Root cert

There are many individual certs, but only 1 intermediate cert and 1 root cert.

I am wondering how to put those certs into java trust store? I think only put intermediate cert is enough, is that right?

Comment: You cert is:individual cert signed by Intermediate cert signed by Root cert ?

Comment: yes, indivisal is signed by intermediate and signed by root

Comment: I think what you are going to do is using Intermediate cert to verify individual cert.So you dont need to store all individual certs,just verify them when you encontered one.

Answer (score 0):

Either the intermediate cert or the root cert should do it.

It is hard to say which one is better.  It is a trade-off between the convenience of not having to add other intermediate certs and potentially trusting too much ... if there are other intermediate certs of the root cert that you don't want to trust.